# Date Format in 1st of Jan , 2012 SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

In Mysql i have a column sdob. I have extracted date from sdob by doing in this way

```
DATE_FORMAT(sdob, '%d %b %Y (%a )')
```

How can i add 'st' to day 1 'nd' to day 2 and 'rd' to day 3. Please suggest

Comment: Added mysql tag because `date_fromat()` is a MySQL function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try capital "D":

```
DATE_FORMAT(sdob, '%D %b %Y (%a )')
```

The documentation for the patterns is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).